# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar una cadena (string) de forma descendente según su longitud?

Tags: python, string, ordenamiento

¿Cómo puedo ordenar una cadena (string) de forma descendente, es decir que desde la palabra mas larga a la mas corta?

Answer (score 3):

Supongo que podrías hacer algo asi:

```
>>> cadena = 'hola me llamo Cesar y soy de Peru'
>>> sorted(cadena.split(), key=lambda palabra: len(palabra), reverse=True)
['llamo', 'Cesar', 'hola', 'Peru', 'soy', 'me', 'de', 'y']
```

Comment: con reverse=True, ¿no se ordenarían al revés?

Comment: @Elenasys el está pidiendo orden de longitud **descendente**

Comment: Con `key=len` es suficiente :)

Comment: @astrojuanlu claro, pero creo que asi es mas entendible

Answer (score 3):

Si es un **string** conteniendo varias palabras se puede ordenar con:

```
misPaises = "Mexico Rumania Argentina Espana Uruguay Peru Ecuador Chile"
for i in reversed(sorted(misPaises.split(), key=lambda item: len(item))):
    print i
```

Salida:

```
Argentina
Ecuador
Uruguay
Rumania
Espana
Mexico
Chile
Peru
```

Si es un **lista** se puede ordenar con:

```
misPaises = ["México", "Rumania", "Argentina", "España",
             "Uruguay", "Peru", "Ecuador", "Chile"]

for i in reversed(sorted(misPaises, key=len)):
    print i
```

Salida:

```
Argentina
Ecuador
Uruguay
España
Rumania
México
Chile
Peru
```

Comment: En el segundo caso, _España_ abajo _Rumania_... La razón es Python 2. Hay que declarar unicode (`u'España'`), o empezar con `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.

Answer (score -1):

Adicional al ordenamiento por la longitud más larga de la palabra también deberia conservar el orden alfabético. Si es el caso :

```
     cadena = 'Cómo puedo ordenar una cadena de forma descendente, es decir que desde la palabra mas larga a la mas corta'
     palabras=sorted(cadena.split(), key=lambda palabra: "%03d%s" % (len(palabra),palabra.lower()), reverse=True)
     print(palabras)
```

Lo que da como resultado:

```
    ['descendente,', 'palabra', 'ordenar', 'cadena', 'puedo', 'larga', 'forma', 'desde', 'decir', 'corta', 'Cómo', 'una', 'que', 'mas', 'mas', 'la', 'la', 'es', 'de', 'a']
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
    cadena="México Rumania Argentina España Uruguay Peru Ecuador Chile"
    palabras=sorted(cadena.split(), key=lambda palabra: "%03d%s" % (len(palabra),palabra.lower()), reverse=True)
    print(palabras)
```

Resultado:

```
    ['Argentina', 'Uruguay', 'Rumania', 'Ecuador', 'México', 'España', 'Chile', 'Peru']
```

Comment: Por ejemplo en esta respuesta añades un requerimiento innecesario que el OP no ha señalado por lo que si un usuario ingresa a esta publicación no le agradara tu respuesta ya que solo distrae.

Comment: Ok  Tienes razón.  Nadie me pidió eso. En este caso , mejor retiro la pregunta?